# Output a specific part of a html page in php

Tags: php, html

Hi there I have this php page that basically looks different depending on user input. If the user has logged-on then I output a html-table represeting a logged-in user. If a user failed to logg-in I output a html-table represeting a failing-logged in user, i.e some red text and such. The problem is that right now Im doing this by outputting(php echo function) html strings. This is really bad and If I have to change something its a pain in the *ss.

Is there any way for me to create a html-file that just contains a table and then output that ?

Or maybe I could create a full html-page but only output the table part of it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the meanwhile, you can simply create the files, and then `include` them in the page.

A more robust system generally requires a better design from the get go.

Comment: Why, because it's short? It gives a concise and exact solution to OP's problem. Not all answers need to contain code or be 10 lines long.

Comment: Hmm but If I include a html file as a whole, wont that mess up the rest of the page ?

Comment: @user3742045 You don't have to write the full HTML page, just the part that you need, i.e. the table (without doctype, head, body, etc). Thne include it in the correct place.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I don't know a PHP function named `read`.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I'm also not familiar with the technique. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're asking if you can `INCLUDE` a file using an if statement. Something like:

```
if ($user == "loggedin") include ("loggedin.php");
```

The answer is no.  I've tried that.

If you want to make HTML markup cleaner (by which I mean not echo 1 line at a time) what you can do is use heredocs:

```
$loggedin = <<<someText
<table><tbody><tr><td>Hello $username</td></tr></tbody></table>
someText;

if ($user == "loggedin") echo $loggedin;
```

You don't even have to save it as a variable, you just echo it:

```
echo <<<someMore
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td>You last logged in $logdate</td>
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
someMore;
```

Heredocs will come out on the page exactly as you put them in, except you can use PHP variable inside them.  You can even use array variables inside a heredoc like this:

```
echo <<<somearrays
{$arrayname1[$i]}<br>
{$arrayname2[5]}<br>
{$arrayname3[7]}<br>
somearrays;
```

To clarify: you either say `echo` or `$variable =`
then put <<< (which is the keyword for heredoc)
put a heredoc name (somearrays in this example)
put your HTML text
end it with the heredoc name and a semicolon

Answer (score -1):

You could create different html files, and output the desired one using:

```
echo file_get_contents( 'Path/to/your/specific file/' );
```

link to `file_get_contents` API http://php.net/file_get_contents

---

#### Edit:

As you can follow from the comments bellow, I believe that `include` is a better solution

Comment: @SecondRikudo and for what reason?!

Comment: Because that's *exactly* what `include` is for. There's no point in loading the entire file to memory.

Comment: It's valid, it's correct, but it's not **helpful**. There's absolutely no reason to load the entire file to memory just to output it. And what if the file weighs 100MB? You'd waste 100MB or RAM per request? Hell no. Not to mention what would happen if there would be some PHP code in the included file. It'll get outputted to the page.

Comment: Well, that make more sense, and I can understand it if you put it like this, honestly, I didn't think about it that way, now I can only agree with you, thanks for the hint :)